# MJML-based emails getting aggressively clipped by Gmail

Tags: email, gmail, html-email, mjml

For the news outlet I work for, we use MJML-created templates to send out our newsletters, some of which can get pretty long. We had never run into the message clipped problem in Gmail through the several months we've been using MJML, but last week, all of our emails, even the shorter ones, are being clipped in Gmail. I've read that emails larger than 102kb are clipped, but my longest email clocks in at 60kb.

Does anyone know if something changed in the way Gmail determines what gets clipped?

I can share the code for my most recent clipped email if it helps.

Comment: We can't do much without the code, so please share. I've not heard about a change in Gmail, and my tests show no change.